# how to represent a specific calendar period (month, week, etc.)

Tags: java, jodatime

I understand that the main concepts in Joda time are:

- instant in time with millisecond granularity (represented by `DateTime`)
- `Interval` representing the span of two instances
- duration which is really only an `long` number of milliseconds
- a `Period` which is like an un-anchored length of time defined not in terms of a precise number of milliseconds but according to common civil usage of concepts like "month", "day", etc.

How should I then represent, e.g. "February 2014". Is there a type for that? I understand I can represent it as a tuple of an instant in time (at the beginning or end of that month) and a `Period` of one month. But this means that I define my own types on top of `Joda` and I have to decide on a convention on whether the instant should be at the beginning or the end of the period I wish to define (since both options are clearly viable).

The use case I am having is that I need to produce reports and it does make a difference (on the report header / description) if the user:

- simply happened to select two instances in time which were exactly at the start and end of February 2014
- selected to produce a monthly report for February 2014.

So, is there a single type for that? and, failing, that, what would be the best approach to represent that.

Comment: I had the same requirement when implementing reports. I ended up with implementing my own class, containing startdate, enddate, periodName, periodType(week,month,quarter,...) and some methods like `isInPeriod(DateTime), isAfterPeriod(DateTime), isBeforePeriod(DateTime)`.

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## tl;dr

Use the modern *java.time* classes that supplant both the Joda-Time project and the troublesome old legacy date-time classes originally bundled with the earliest versions of Java.

```
YearMonth.of( 2014 , Month.FEBRUARY )
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* (JSR 310) classes that are the official successor to the Joda-Time project. Both projects are led by the same man, Stephen Colebourne.

### `YearMonth`

> How should I then represent, e.g. "February 2014".

Use the [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html), purpose-built for that.

You can specify a year and month by number, using sane numbering 1-12 for January-December (unlike the legacy classes).

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of( 2014 , 2 ) ;  // 2014 February.
```

Or use the handy [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of( 2014 , Month.FEBRUARY ) ;
```

### ISO 8601

To represent the year-month as text, use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format: YYYY-MM

```
String output = ym.toString() ;
```

> 2014-02

And [parse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) such strings.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.parse( "2014-02" ) ;
```

No database I know of has a year-month data type. So I suggest using a text column in your table that holds ISO 8601 formatted strings. Note that the alphabetical sorting of this ISO 8601 format happens to also be chronologically sorted.

### `Period`

> a Period of one month.

A `Period` is not attached to the timeline. Something like `Period.ofMonths( 1 )` represents a generic month unrelated to any date or calendar.

In contrast, a `YearMonth` represents one *specific* month. A `YearMonth` *is* attached to the timeline.

### Moments

If you need specific date-with-time moments such as for a query into a database, you will need to determine dates. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate ldStart = ym.atDay( 1 ) ;                 // First of the month.
LocalDate ldStop = ym.plusMonths( 1 ).atDay( 1 ) ;  // First day of the following month.
```

Determining date-with-time values requires a time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date-with-time. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

Use that zone to let *java.time* determine the first moment of the day. Do not assume the day starts at 00:00:00. Some dates in some zones start at another time-of-day such as 01:00:00.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = ldStart.atZone( z ) ;  // First moment of the day starting in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).
ZonedDateTime zdtStop = ldStop.atZone( z ) ;
```

You can then extract UTC values, which are usually used by databases to store a value in a column of SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

```
Instant instantStart = zdtStart.toInstant() ;
Instant instantStop = zdtStop.toInstant() ;
```

### JDBC

As of JDBC 4.2 and later, you can exchange *java.time* objects with your database.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instantStart ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instantStop ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Class [YearMonth](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/YearMonth.html) in [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) provides this functionality, for months.

So, to get the January 1970 and the seconds-since-the-epoch values at the start and end instances of the first month of the Epoch:

```
    YearMonth yearMonth = new YearMonth (1970, 1);
    Interval interval = yearMonth.toInterval(DateTimeZone.UTC);
    int startSSE = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(interval.getStartMillis());
    int   endSSE = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(interval.getEndMillis());
    System.out.printf("%d -> %d (%4.6f days)\n", startSSE, endSSE, ((float)(endSSE-startSSE))/(24*60*60));
```

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). The *java.time* framework offers its own version of [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html).

Answer (score 0):

Currently my luck with the Joda-Time YearMonth class is not good so here is an alternative example using DateTimeFormatter.

```
public static DateTimeFormatter DATEFORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("MMM, YYYY").toFormatter();
```

An example piece of code that I added a println() for your benefit.

```
/**
     * calculates the number of months between the upper and lower bounds 
     * example: int m = numberOfMonths("January, 2009", "May, 2000");   
     *          >m=104
     * Uses Joda
     * Months are full month names
     * @return
     */
    public int numberOfMonths(String upperMMMMcommaYYYY, String lowerMMMMcommaYYYY){
        DateTime upper = DATEFORMATTER.parseDateTime(upperMMMMcommaYYYY);
        DateTime lower = DATEFORMATTER.parseDateTime(lowerMMMMcommaYYYY);
        Months m = Months.monthsBetween(lower, upper);
        System.out.println(upperMMMMcommaYYYY.concat("printed from DateTime looks like ".concat(upper.toString(DATEFORMATTER))));
        return m.getMonths;

    }
```

the println result -> January, 2009 using DateTimeFormatter + DateTime looks like Jan, 2009

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). The *java.time* framework offers its own version of [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html).